# System did not generate an Id for my new xml layout and show me same errors

Tags: android, xml, layout, adt

I have 2 problem that I think both of them is for one reason:

1. When I try to add a new XML layout; that XML fail add successfully but in "Console" show me it:

   ```
   [2014-05-04 18:41:11 - Example] W/ResourceType( 5804): ResXMLTree_node size 0 is smaller than header size 0x14.
   [2014-05-04 18:41:11 - Example] D:\Android\Workspace\Example\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'actionLayout' with value '@android:layout/').
   ```

   and I can get resource to it in classes.
2. In "problem" tab:

   ```
   Errors:   Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.
   Location: line 1
   Type:     Android ADT Problem
   ```

   and I cant solve it

Please same one help me ...

Comment: Click on the error and hit the delete button. It's a false positive. It happens, sometimes.

Comment: I tried your offer but when I try to run App both of them is back.

Comment: Sometimes it does it repeatedly. But it runs, then. Also @Lal is saying the very same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out. So for anyone else still on the learning curve with me, the solultion is as noted in my comment. In addition -

aapt = Android Asset Packaging Tool From the [Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html#detailed-build) - "The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) takes your application resource files, such as the AndroidManifest.xml file and the XML files for your Activities, and compiles them."

The solution for me was simply to delete the error on the 'Problem' window (right click | delete). Then, force a rebuild by rerunning the app. Any remaining problems will now show up and be logged so you can track them down.

Hope this is helpful to others.

Comment: I restarted from last version backup